# Routing in Blazor does not work, parameter passed is always null

Tags: blazor, parameter-passing, url-routing

I have a simple razor component looking like this

```
@page "/einsatz"
@page "/einsatz/{ScaledTable}"

@code {
    [Parameter] 
    public string ScaledTable { get; set; } 

    private string Test { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Test = ScaledTable;   // ScaledTable is NULL here
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        Table = ScaledTable;  // ScaledTable is NULL here
    }
}
```

I try to call the component with the following URLs

```
https://localhost:60711/einsatz
```

=> `ScaledTable` is null as expected

```
https://localhost:60711/einsatz/test
```

=> Exception

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () all.css:1
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () site.css:1
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () blazor.server.js:1
> ... and so on
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> telerik-blazor.js:1

```
https://localhost:60711/einsatz?scaledtable=test
```

=> `ScaledTable` is NULL here also - why!?

If I try this page directives instead:

```
@page "/einsatz"
@page "/einsatz/{ScaledTable:string}"
```

I get an exception at startup of the app

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.Refresh(Boolean isNavigationIntercepted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)

What am I doing wrong here? What I am misunderstanding here?

**Edited** 26.02.2023/18:03

First of all, the error for

```
@page "/einsatz/{ScaledTable:string}"
```

is by design, since you have not to specify string type for parameter.

Looking further into the exception, using

```
@page "/einsatz/{ScaledTable}"
```

I found out, that these errors come from wrong routes, generated for the files in the layout. The try to load

```
localhost:60711/einsatz/_framework/blazor.server.js
```

fails with HTTP 404 of cause, because there should be no "einsatz" in this URL, something seems to be wrong here anywhere ...

Comment: I tested it on blazor server and https://localhost:7127/einsatz/hello works as expected. The variable is set. Must be something else that you are doing. Maybe try with a vanilla project and see if it works?  As for @page "/einsatz/{ScaledTable:string}" throwing an exception, see https://mattjameschampion.com/2022/04/29/null-reference-exception-in-blazor-router/

Comment: Thank you, I tired this too now, and it works out of the box.
Looking further into the exception of my main app I can see, that if I try to call localhost:1111/einsatz/hello the server tries to load URL: https://localhost:60711/einsatz/_framework/blazor.server.js which is wrong, since there should be no "einsatz" in this path, so it seems it is a problem generating the routes for the links in the main page .... !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the error I made.

I have to add the following line to the _layout.cshtml file:

```
<head>
   <base href="~/" />
   ....
```

Don't know where I have lost this, it is part of any new Blazor project.